# Remove n number of rows from a list

Tags: c#, list

How do I remove the last two rows from a List.

At present, I am removing the 2  rows manually as shown below. However, there might be an instance where I have to define the number of rows to be removed as `n`. So, it will remove `n` number of rows from the bottom of the list. How can I make this change?

```
rows.RemoveAt(rows.Count - 1);
rows.RemoveAt(rows.Count - 2);
```

Comment: There's a bug in your code. Once you've removed the last item with `rows.RemoveAt(rows.Count - 1);`, the code to remove the next last item is `rows.RemoveAt(rows.Count - 1);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`RemoveRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_RemoveRange_System_Int32_System_Int32_):

```
rows.RemoveRange(rows.Count - n, n);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ:

```
rows = rows.Take(rows.Count - n).ToList();
```

Comment: I did not downwote, but technically you do not remove two items. You create new list. The original list is unchanged and if you need items removed there, it does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

As Spender said, there is a potential issue in your code. I call this a "Index Race Condition". After you remove the last element, something else becomes the new last Element. It is something you have to look out for with Indexed Collections. Keyd collections do not suffer from it.

In addition to what others said regarding using "RemoveRange" (if availible) or LINQ, there is also a chance you got the wrong collection type.

The [Queue[T]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and the [Stack[T]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) are specialized collections for first-in, first-out and first-in, last-out cases respectively.